# How to make result of Promise all in order

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Question:
the output of case1 is from 0 to 4 which is in order while
the output of case2 is in random.

I know the reason why case1's result is in order is that the request is send after the result of previous request comes.
In case2 the request will not wait the result of previous request.

my question is that is there a way to retain the result of case2 in order too?

case1

```
const main = async () => {
    const arr = Array.of(...[1,2,3,4,5])

    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        console.log(`request:${i}`)
        const res = await request(i)
        console.log(res)
    }


    console.log("next step")

}

const request = (i:number):Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise<number>(((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve(i)
        },Math.random() * 1000)
    }))
}
```

output1

```
closure
request:0
0
request:1
1
request:2
2
request:3
3
request:4
4
next step
```

case2

```
const main = async () => {
    const arr = Array.of(...[1,2,3,4,5])
    await Promise.all(arr.map(async (v,i) => {
        console.log(`request:${v}`)
        const res = await request(v)
        console.log(`result:${res}`)
        console.log(res)
    })).catch((e) => {

    })


    console.log("next step")

}

const request = (i:number):Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise<number>(((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve(i)
        },Math.random() * 1000)
    }))
}

main()
```

output2

```
request:1
request:2
request:3
request:4
request:5
result:4
4
result:5
5
result:1
1
result:3
3
result:2
2
next step
```

Comment: No *reasonable* way without removing the `Promise.all` entirely, I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Promise.all()` returns an array of the results in the same order; they just won't resolve in order. You could return the response within your `request` promise, and...

```
const [result1, result2, result3] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
```

Or if you wanted to iterate over an array...

```
const results = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
```

Comment: Hi Ben Chamberlin
The results is kept in order in this way, and the requests are sent in order
can we keep each request to be sent only after response of previous request?
juest like
request0
response0
request1
response1
request2
response2
.....
requestn
responseN

Comment: @ZhongweiXu if you want to only run the next promise after the previous has resolved, you'll want to await each one individually. `Promise.all()` should only be used if you want to run them all at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Promise All should be array of request or promise, in map() should return request.
try this

```js
const main =  () => {
    const arr = Array.of(...[1,2,3,4,5])
     Promise.all(arr.map((v,i) => {
        console.log(`request:${v}`)
         return  request(v)   
    })).then((res)=>{
    res.forEach((val)=>{
        console.log(`result:${val}`)
    })
       
    }).catch((e) => {

    })
    console.log("next step")

}

 const request = (i)=> {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve(i)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)*1000)
    })
} 

main()
```

Comment: Hey, ranganathan
Can Promise All let the request to be send only after the response of previous request?
like this

```
request0
response0
request1
response1
request2
response2
.....
requestn
responseN
```

Comment: hi, i think using Promise All that cannot be achieve try async and wait